# Iron Router Mysterious Delay

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Let's say there are two routes: `/posts` and `/posts/:id`. The first route has to render many (about a hundered) posts at the same time, and the second route just shows a detailed view of a post. The user will go back and forth the two routes multiple times. It would be a jarring experience if he had to wait for a long time between every navigation.

To prevent such loading problem, I am using `subs-manager` that preserves a subscription of data between routes. After the initial loading of the posts, all the posts are preserved, and subscription is always ready. My problem is that the even when the subscription is ready, it takes about a full second for `/posts` to load.

More precisely, after `Route.go('/posts')` is called, it takes 1 second before everything is loaded. I am using Iron Router, and considering to switch to Flow Router in the hope of solving this problem.

**Question:** Where does this delay come from, and how can I solve this problem?

**Edit:** After more investigation, the delay happens in between `onCreated` and `onRendered`.

Comment: Are you using `waitOn` for your subscriptions in iron-router? Are you stopping your subscriptions anywhere? If you never stop your subscriptions multiple subscriptions to the same collection should be *additive* (i.e. a *union* of data) and should not start/stop collections. When you posted this question earlier you were managing your subscriptions in your Template *onCreated* callbacks. Is that still the case?

Comment: how big is the collection for `/posts`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz About ~150 posts.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend limiting your posts to as many fit in the screen and then a few after, that maybe 10 to (15 - 30), then implement pagination. 

If you're doing any server side joins I'd recommend looking into "template-level reactive join" David Weldon has a great article : https://dweldon.silvrback.com/template-joins

Comment: @Perspective thank you! In fact, I am doing infinite scrolling and I load 20 posts at a time. The problem is, once you have loaded 150 posts, go to postsDetailed view, and go back to the index page, now you have 150 posts to render instead of 20.

Comment: I'm assuming this by design as a UX feature, so the person does not have to load all 150 posts again? If that's the case you might want to try this package: https://github.com/meteorhacks/fast-render or program some other solutions. Again perhaps client side subs, or some how load 20 stories from where the user last left and infinite scroll backwards, which sounds stupid, but it's an option.